# Define Line by line Editext Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to write  something like this:

> Today is monday   //this is 20 characters now i want to skip to new line
>
> Tommorow is  //20 chars it skipped a line because the last input was a complete word.
>
> monday //this was skipped because the word over reached 20 chars.

How do I achieve the maximum char per line and assign carriage return (If the word is incomplete moves the word to new line) when it hits 20 characters?

Could be used in for example:

> A novel writing program.

I think I have to use some sort of read function for each character entered.

Comment: Check for text length whenever you add it and then add a \n? Of course keeping track of the lines, resetting the char counter.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on what effect you want to achieve. Your first example, "tomorrow is mond", implies you want words to be cut off when you hit the 20char limit, irrespective of whether or not they are completed. but your edit suggests otherwise. Can I just confirm what effect you're after?

Comment: I want the last one. Where monday is not cut off. Where monday is displayed on a new line

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you could use `TextWatcher` to achieve this effect. One possible solution could be to listen out for the previous line break, and set an automatic line break after 20 chars:

```
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if ((editText.length()%20) == 0){
                editText.getText().insert(editText.length(), "\n");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

I doubt that this would work on a swipe keyboard though. It would also prevent you from being able to use backspace to go back to the previous line. To counteract this would require something more elaborate - you could use a `for` loop to constantly listen for the last line break in `beforeTextChanged`, or use a `Boolean` switch with an Override on `onKey` for `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop through your string and place a `\n` every time your counter reaches 20, or until you reach the end of your string.

Comment: Sorry I meant to write eidt text not textview. Updated.

Comment: The answer below outlines the text watcher nicely